# LISP and Scheme in microcontoller programming

Tags: lisp, scheme, microcontroller

Do LISP and/or Scheme useful in microcontroller programming? Are LISP and Scheme good in this area in comparing with C?

Answer (score 1):

Lisp and Scheme are high level languages, with garbage collection and lots of abstraction from the hardware. They do get used occasionally for microcontroller programming though. Mostly Scheme since Scheme is easier to embed. This is a good example of [low level Scheme](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stamourv/papers/picobit.pdf)

The other examples of Scheme/Lisp in low level stuff mostly is something along the lines of

```
Lisp --> C --> Profit
```

So if that sounds good to you, check out [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,55873.0.html) for the arduino.

Check out Forth though, it has a lot of the same ideas as Lisps and is used in microcontroller programming. [GForth](http://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/) is a pretty nice implementation.